# Optimization of parsing a specific format string in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I need to parse a message which is being passed to the stored procedure. The format of the message could look a like `##tag##message`

I wrote some lines in the sproc which basically does the job, but i am looking to optimize it in such a way that extra variable declarations can be removed if possible.

```
DECLARE @message VARCHAR(255)='##cloud##this is a cloud related message';
DECLARE @temp VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @searchTag VARCHAR(255)
IF  SUBSTRING(@message,1,2)='##'
BEGIN
    SET @temp = STUFF(@message,1,2,'');
    SET @i = CHARINDEX('##',@temp);
    IF (@i>0)
    BEGIN
        set @searchTag= SUBSTRING(@temp,1,@i-1);
        set @message=STUFF(@temp,1,@i+1,'')
    END
END
SELECT @searchTag, @message
```

In case, if the format is not correct i need to select Null and original message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course remove `@temp` variable:

```
declare
    @message varchar(255)='##cloud##this is a cloud related message',
    @i int,
    @searchTag varchar(255)

if @message like '##%##%'
begin
    set @message = stuff(@message, 1, 2, '')
    set @i = charindex('##', @message)

    select
        @searchTag = left(@message, @i - 1),
        @message = stuff(@message, 1, @i + 1, '')
end

select @searchTag, @message
```

But logically, SQL Server has to pass the string twice then - to check if there's 2 occurences of `##` and then another time when parsing.

Another way to do this is to use `@searchTag` instead of `@temp` variable:

```
declare
    @message varchar(255)='##cloud##this is a cloud related message',
    @i int,
    @searchTag varchar(255)

if left(@message, 2) = '##'
begin
    set @searchTag = stuff(@message, 1, 2, '')
    set @i = charindex('##', @searchTag)

    if @i <= 0
    begin
        set @searchTag = null
    end
    else
    begin
        set @message = stuff(@searchTag, 1, @i + 1, '')
        set @searchTag = left(@searchTag, @i - 1)
    end
end

select @searchTag, @message
```

**update** If you really wants to get rid of variables, first method also could be rewritten like this:

```
declare
    @message varchar(255)='##cloud##this is a cloud related message',
    @searchTag varchar(255)

if @message like '##%##%'
begin
    set @message = stuff(@message, 1, 2, '')

    select
        @searchTag = left(@message, charindex('##', @message) - 1),
        @message = stuff(@message, 1, len(@searchTag) + 2, '')
end

select @searchTag, @message
```

Comment: Absolute stunning.  Is there any disadvantage of the first approach you mentioned?

Comment: well, as I've said - it could be a bit worse in performance, because you have to check if the string fits and then parse it, so to do the same work twice

Comment: yeah, but are there any chances of failure in the first approach

Comment: @ManishRawat nope, if your string is `like '##%##%'` then there're not

Comment: of course, if your @message will be, for example `####`, then you'll recive empty strings for both variables